# Before Decodefile how to get height and width of the image in android?

Tags: android

How can I set the isSamplesize according to the device? e.g. for 5MP,8MP,13Mp camera the image size varies. How to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `BitmapFactory.Options.inJustDecodeBounds` ([Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inJustDecodeBounds)):

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

// now width and height are in options.outWidth and options.outHeight
```

Going from that, you can calculate `inSampleSize`, [here's one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494114/android-how-to-create-an-efficient-copy-of-mutable-bitmap) (haven't tested it)